# System.IO.FileNotFoundException encountered while file uploading using FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, filenotfoundexception

I have following code that I am using to upload an image to my website. The image is first uploaded to a temporary folder then it get resized after that the new image is uploaded to main image folder.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/tmpimg.jpg"));
System.Drawing.Image originalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/tmpimg.jpg"));
System.Drawing.Image MainImg = new SPCL().ResizeImage(originalImage, 700, 600, false);
MainImg.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Home/Home1.jpg"));
```

This is giving following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\site\wwwroot\TEMP\tmpimg.jpg at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) at Settings.saveImages() at Settings.saveSettings()
at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement) at Settings.saveImages() at Settings.saveSettings()
```

I have set all the write permissions on the folder and even tried making all permissions enabled on all folders of the website (when I got irritated ;))

The error is coming at this line `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/tmpimg.jpg"));`

The file is not being created at the specified path.
Please any one have any idea why this is happening and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: How that's gonna work? You are using `originalImage` before its definition. It will surely give a null value. or I think it will be a compiler error.

Comment: okay.. let me try your solution, then will tell you..

Comment: also for future references I would wrap that code in a `try{}catch{}`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tried your solution..but the situation is still same...

Comment: Shiva can you post full Method code where you have this code.. ? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22641/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-shiva-pareek)

Comment: The SaveSettings() function is called by Button_click() and then SaveSettings does nothing but call SaveImages() function and then a database function. But since error is coming in SaveImages() so the database function is not being called. So you see this is the only complete code that I can give you, there's nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution to the problem. And posting the answer in hope that it might solve someone else's same problem in future.

**I solved this issue by removing the update panel that was enclosing the FileUpload Control**.

Also you can check this link [update panel with file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042632/update-panel-with-file-upload) [Refered by: Shadow Wizard] for solving this problem without removing update panel.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042632/update-panel-with-file-upload

Comment: Shiva that's awesome, I didn't know that you had used an update panel if so I would have been able to help you resolve this issue much quicker.. awesome job for sticking with trying to solve your issue and succeeding +1

Comment: thanks @ShadowWizard for the link. That explained me the reason.

Comment: thanks @DJKRAZE. I thought that it has nothing to do with update panel. But when all the things I tried, this was the last trick remaining so I applied that and it worked. :)

Comment: Not a problem Shiva.. I know that Panels are different in winforms vs Web forms and especially Update Panels because of the Partial PostBack aspect there are many that have this issue but after digging they usually figure it out as well as you have.. good job figuring it out by the way..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: thanks mate for all the useful info. I learned a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome Shiva..that is what the best thing about coding is.. not only doing..but learning by what we do.. good luck and will talk to you soon

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are hard coding the name or the file from the FileUpload.SaveAs() method try something like this

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/"), FileUpload1.FileName));
```

if there is a Folder on the Server Root.. you need to add it to the Temp/someFolderName/
Try setting up a Virutal Directory as well to write to that folder.

You could also thy something like this

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/TEMP/"), FileUpload1.FileName));
```

[HttpPostedFileClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Referenced from MSDN this has been tested so you could follow something like this. Keep in mind that if this code does not work perhaps it's a permissions issue on your end.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        Boolean fileOK = false;
        String path = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages/");
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
        {
            String fileExtension = 
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
            String[] allowedExtensions = 
                {".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg"};
          for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
          {
               if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
               {
                    fileOK = true;
               }
          }
        }

        if (fileOK)
        {
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path 
                    + FileUpload1.FileName);
                Label1.Text = "File uploaded!";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "File could not be uploaded.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: psst, missing an end parenthesis. `FileUpload1.FileName));`

Comment: the first code didn't worked. I will try the second one and let you know

Comment: @DJKRAZE : I solved the issue and I posted the solution as an answer. Please have a look at it.